# Cardinality proof verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals, real-numbers

***Problem:***

Let $C \subset (0,1)$ be the set of all numbers whose unique decimal representation contains the number seven. Show that the number of elements in $C$ must be the same as the number of elements in $(0,1)$.

***My solution:***

We must construct a bijective function between $C$ and $(0,1)$ Let $(d_n)$ be the unique decimal representation of $x$.

Since $ \forall \space\space x\in C \space\space \exists! \space\space (d_n): x= (d_n) \space \implies f:C \to (0,1)\space\space s.t\space\space f(x) =x $ is injective.

Now we must show surjectivity, that is $ \forall x \in C \space\space f(x_1) \not = (fx_2) \implies x_1 \not = x_2$.

Let $f(x_1) = d_1$ and $f(x_2) = d_2$ since $d_n$ is unique $\implies f(x_1) \not = f(x_2) \implies (d_1) \not = (d_2) \implies x_1 \not = x_2 \forall x \in C$.

So the function is bijective and therefore the number of elements in C is the same as the number of elements in (0,1).

Any pointers? This is literally just a stab at this...I don't know if this is at all sufficient. Any advice would be great.

Comment: That is *not* the definition of surjectivity.

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought, I have to show that all (0,1) is reached right?

Comment: $f$ is just the inclusion map, that sends any $x \in C$ to itself, which is well-defined as $C \subseteq (0,1)$. This is of course injective. But not every element of $(0,1)$ is of this form, like 0.10000, etc. That's the whole point.

Comment: So any advice on what I actually have to show? That f reaches every element of (0,1) right?

Comment: $f$ does not reach it. So your $f$ (which is essentially the identity) is not the right approach. Try to find an injection from $(0,1)$ to $C$ instead (and apply Cantor-Bernstein), so map a number with any decimal representation to one that has a $7$ in it, in an injective way.

Comment: Okay, but basically the first part of my proof (with the identity) shows that the number of elements in C is less than or equal to number of elements in (0,1). So, what you're saying is, if I find an injection the other way (from (0,1) to C) I can use cantor bernstein to argue that they are equal, yes?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I propose you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy enough to make an injection either way: $C\subseteq (0,1)$ is the obvious injection one way, and for the other, there is a very simple bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0.7,0.8)\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $C$ is a proper subset of $(0,1)$, just as you noted in first words of the problem statement, so $$|C|\le |(0,1)|$$
OTOH, there is an injection $(0,1)\to C$, defined as follows:

- if a decimal expansion of a number contains sevens, replace every $7$ with $77$,
- otherwise, insert $7$ just after a decimal point

which implies $$|(0,1)| \le |C|$$
Now the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) states that the two sets are equipollent: $$|C| = |(0,1)|$$